# Touch Event in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I am building a tile application, which can be dragged and swiped. Currently, I have the entire block of tiles being added as a subview. I was curious what would be the better way to drag the tile element and if place on top of another element, the element swap's its location coordinates.

```
Swaps when placent A to B
View A <- -> View B 

To 

View B <- -> View A
```

I have looked into touch event's but then its based on any view. Also I have looked into UIGestureRecognizer, but I was wondering if there are any good frameworks which can handle that, or any better way of doing than.

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily create this system by overriding touch events on super view. On touches begin find out what subview was hit, on touches moved just move its center to touch location and on touches ended check again what view it was dropped on and swap those 2 views.

You have many convenient methods on `UIView` that will help you with that: `pointInside`, `convertPoint`, `convertRect`. You might only need `pointInside` for your purpose.

So in this case you should set `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` for tiles and handle touches in their superview. To make a hit check just use a `for` loop and `pointInside` but on touches ended you should skip the check on the view that is currently being dragged.

**EDIT:** UIPanGestureRecognizer comment

`UIPanGestureRecognizer` might actually work, though you benefit very little of it. You will be able to get the view it is panning instantly but that is about it. You still need to find the view it is over through something like a `for` loop. The location of the gesture will need to be converted to the superview coordinates (if not, you will always receive the same coordinate because you move the view itself). The drawback is you will not instantly get events for panning, you will have to start dragging the view for a few pixels to receive the pan beginning, you on the other hand would probably like to instantly bring the view a bit to front or do some other animation to notify the user that this view is movable.

Anyway, UIPanGestureRecognizer is meant for panning and is designed that way. Although it might be possible to use it for your purpose you might find yourself in doing more work then it would be with simple touch events.

Comment: Thanks Matic and aug2uag for your suggestions, but do you think UIGestureRecognizerPan could be more beneficial as it will be utilized for each view differently? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the `[touches anyObject]` message may be a good option for you

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   [self methodToChangeView]; 
}
```

with the following method

```
- (void)methodToChangeView {
     MyNewViewController *myNewViewController = [[MyNewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyNewViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myNewViewController animated:YES];
}
```